# Help updating MPD from V16 to V19 on 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, gcc, git, mpd

I am trying to update MPD from V16 to V19 on my Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried to download and compile from source, and met with dozens of outdated support files including a too old `gcc`, no ability to get Boost, and can't get ICU at all.

I tried to use `git`, but the instructions [here](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Repositories), like most instructions I have found for updating Linux apps in general, are wholly inadequate.

Specifically, I did:

```
git clone git://git.musicpd.org/master/mpd.git
```

Then I moved to `/usr/bin` (I think there is where the mpd program is), and did `git pull`. I get a

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Can someone please help me do this?

Comment: It's not worth the trouble, because to get the latest version, you'll need to update half the distro. 12.04 is good but quite old, there is about 6 months of support left. It's about time to plan an upgrade, and 16.04 has the latest version of mpd in the repositories.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am finding. I hate upgrading to new versions, they always try to sneak in more bloat, not to mention most of the apps will end up getting hosed in the processes. But, sigh, I am writing a MPD client, and I must have the latest version for the features I want to test, so... , there go my next two days.

Comment: "they always try to sneak in more bloat" Are program and security updates "bloat"? Also keep in mind you'll have to upgrade some time, in this case Ubuntu 12.04 supports ends in 6 months.

Comment: Security updates may be OK, program updates for the sake of updating , IMHO, generally not so much. Lots of times a program is working just fine and an update break it. Bloat? In V12, Ubuntu added MOTD so they could send "messages" to the user, just a path for ads, I wonder what they will add in V16.